# Infinitesimal Robustness, influence function of $T$ at $F$

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, estimation, robust

This text is taken from **Introduction to robust estimation and hypothesis testing. Wilcox R.**

First I will write down the description that leads to definition of relative influence on $T(F)$ and then I will state my questions.

Consider a mixture of two distributions where an observation is randomly sampled from distribution $F$ with probability $1 − \epsilon$, otherwise sampling is from the distribution $\Delta_x$ . That is, with probability $\epsilon$, the observed value is $ x$. The resulting distribution is $F_{x,\epsilon} = (1 − \epsilon)F + \epsilon \Delta_x$.
But $F$ and $\Delta_x$ are distributions, so |$F(y) − \Delta_x(y)| ≤ 1$. Consequently, the Kolmogorov distance between $F_{x,\epsilon}$, and $F$ is at most $\epsilon$. Moreover, $F(x)$, and $F$ can be made arbitrarily close by choosing

sufficiently small.
The relative influence on $T(F)$ of having the value $x$ occur with probability $\epsilon$ is

$$\frac{T(F_{x,\epsilon})-T(F)}{\epsilon}$$

and the influence function of $T$ at $F$ is
$$IF(x) = \lim \frac{T(F_{x,\epsilon}) − T (F)}{\epsilon}$$

So, I can understand everything until the point where the relative influence on $T(F)$ of having the value $x$ occur with probability $\epsilon$ is defined. It is derivative at point $x$, but why the probability $\epsilon$ is at the same time chosen to be the distance of change in $x$? How is it connected?

Comment: You have not explained what the influence function $T$ actually does.  We need some details about this function to assist.

Comment: @Ben  In the statistics literature, the derivative of a functional, $T(F)$, is called the influence function of $T$ at $F$.

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean by "the probability ϵ is at the same chosen to be the distance of change in x."  Some word(s) may be missing, making it ungrammatical and difficult to make sense of.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @whuber I corrected the sentence. It seems confusing to me that Kolmogorov distance $|F_{x,\epsilon} - F|$is at most $\epsilon$ and at the same time, $\epsilon$ is the probability that the value x will occur.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that, but I suspect that if you were to examine graphs of $F,$ $\Delta_x,$ and $F_{x,\epsilon}$ the relationships would become clear.

Comment: It's the distance from $F$ in the direction of $\Delta_x$.  Technically, without stronger assumptions, $IF(x)$ is a *directional derivative*, more specifically a Gateaux derivative; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative.  You're working in a function space, not with real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working in a function space, specifically, the space of probability distributions equipped with some useful topology.  In this case, we can choose two probability distributions in that space - $F$ and $\Delta_x$ - and we can "draw" a "straight line" between them by varying $\epsilon$ from $0$ to $1$:

$$F_{x,\epsilon} = (1-\epsilon)F(x) + \epsilon\Delta_x$$

We have to do it as a weighted average (as opposed to what you are used to seeing in college Calculus classes where we have $f(x+\epsilon)$ and $f(x)$) because otherwise $F_{x,\epsilon}$ wouldn't be a probability distribution (as it wouldn't integrate to $1$) so wouldn't lie in our space of probability distributions.

Conceptually you can see that all finite mixtures lie in this space too.  We are simply taking one that is very convenient for analyzing the robustness of a functional.

The space we have constructed is analogous to the real line in traditional calculus.  Instead of a function $f(x)$ whose derivative with respect to $x$ we would like to calculate, we have a functional $T(F)$ whose derivative with respect to $F$ *in the direction of* $\Delta_x$ we would like to find.  The derivative is *not* at a (real-valued) point $x$, but at a (probability distribution valued) point $F$.  In this use case, $x$ merely indicates *which* $\Delta$ (i.e., which direction) we are finding the derivative with respect to.

How do we do this?  Well, trying to write more intuitively than mathematically, $F_{x,\epsilon}$ varies continuously with $\epsilon$ (for any $x$), and as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, $F_{x,\epsilon} \rightarrow F$ monotonically.  It seems natural, then, that we would measure the distance between $F_{x,\epsilon}$ and $F$ by $\epsilon$. This leads to the Gateaux derivative, customized to the definition of our space, as:

$$dT(F; \Delta_x) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}{T((1-\epsilon)F + \epsilon\Delta_x) - T(F) \over \epsilon}$$

which is easily seen to be equivalent to the definition of influence function.